# Mono 4 builds .NET 3.5 application with System.Drawing 4.0.0.0 required, how to prevent?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, monodevelop

I have a .NET 3.5 application that uses Windows forms so references System.Drawing 2.0.0.0. Under mono 3.8 and Monodevelop 5 this solution compiles fine and can be run under Windows or Wine with a .NET 3.5 installation.

However with Mono 4.2 and Monodevelop 5 and the same solution & source code the compiled executables fail to run as before as they state they require System.Drawing 4.0.0.0 (exception of Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'). For compatibility the application needs to remain on .NET 3.5. (For information: an installation of wine with .NET 4.5 still fails to run this executable yet a separate test executable using a .NET 4 threading feature runs OK).

I can see from the release notes of mono 4 at http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/4.0.0/ that release 4 is a major new version. From the RPM info of mono-core it also looks like version 3.8 would RPM provide both System.Drawing 2.0.0.0 and System.Drawing 4.0.0.0, whereas mono 4.2 only RPM provides System.Drawing 4.0.0.0. So maybe that is the root of the issue.

So I'm left unable to produce the required compiled executables. Downgrading mono is not desirable as there are other some other useful changes in version 4.

Does anybody have any further information or know of any workarounds for this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Mono 4.0, as you noted, they dropped support for .NET older than 4.0 to reduce the maintenance burden.

It will still *run* .NET 3.5 and 2.0 (and 1.0?) apps, but you won't be able to build them with Mono 4.x.

My suggestion would be to have your official build machines installed with Mono 3.8.